# Extracting all images and text from pdf file

Tags: java, python, node.js, pdf

I need to create json from pdf to render the pdf content as HTML with all the images and text. I have tried the modules below to do that. I am able to extract only plain images now, but not able to extract the graphical images and background shadow images. Is there any module to get these?

Modules tried

```
-PDFMiner (python)
-Mammoth(Node)   
-pdf2json(Node)   
-PDFBox(Java)
```

Comment: What is a *plain image* in contrast to a  *graphical image*? And what exactly is a *background shadow image*? And how did you try with the modules mentioned?

Comment: lpie chart,bar chart are are graphical images..other images are plain.background image is a background shadow image...

Comment: The PDF format does not know pie charts or bar charts as special graphics. It mainly knows text, vector graphics, and bitmap graphics. Probably your "graphical images" fall into one category and your "other images" into another. The PDF format does not globally separate content into background and foreground. Any graphic you perceive as background can also be used as foreground and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://pythonhosted.org/PyMuPDF/. Apparently this product renders pages in various formats, including json. Although I have limited experience with it, the recipe at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580703-extract-images-of-a-pdf-optionally-by-page-using-p/history/1/ shows how to use PyMuPDF to extract images from a PDF.

Comment: i'm getting width and height of the image but not able to get the image coordinates

Comment: You should post this as a new question. Please supply a link to a PDF, preferably a small one that demonstrates the problem you're having, and post your code as well.